# SQL Server - Using joins in Update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, subquery, inner-join

I have a `HRUser` and an `Audit` table, both are in production with large number of rows.

Now I have added one more column to my `HRUser` table called `IsActivated`.

I need to create a one-time script which will be executed in production and populate data into this `IsActivated` column. After execution of this one-time script onwards, whenever the users activate their account, the `HRUser` table's `IsActivated` column will automatically be updated.

For updating the `IsActivated` column in the `HRUser` table, I need to check the `Audit` table whether the user has logged in till now.

```
UPDATE [dbo].HRUser 
SET IsActivated = 1
FROM dbo.[UserAudit] A
JOIN dbo.[HRUser] U ON A.UserId = U.UserId
WHERE A.AuditTypeId = 14
```

`AuditTypeId=14` means the user has logged in and user can login any number of times and every time the user logs in it will get captured in the `UserAudit` table...

The logic is that if the user has logged in at least once means the user is activated.

This cannot be tested on lower environments and it need to be directly executed on production as in lower environments we don’t have any data in the `UserAudit` table.

I am not really sure if that works as I have never used joins in update statement, I am looking for suggestions for any better approach than this for accomplishing my task

Comment: Seems like an `EXISTS` in the `WHERE` would be better here, rather than a `JOIN`; though (assuming that a user can only have 1 row where `AuditTypeId` has a value of `14`) this should work. The only thing that is odd syntax wise is you have `UPDATE [dbo].HRUser` but  `HRUser` appears in the `JOIN`. I would expect `UPDATE U` and then `dbo.[HRUser] U` is in the `FROM` and `dbo.[UserAudit]` is joined to.

Comment: "This cannot be tested ..." Oh yes it certainly can - but laziness prevents you from putting in some fabricated test data. And one should NEVER run a script on a production machine that has not been tested in a QA environment without a very special reason.

Comment: @Larnu there can be multiple entries for a single user in the UserAudit table as a user can login multiple times

Comment: That's why I made the caveat and suggests an `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery to filter on rows whose `UserId` has at least one audit event of id `14`:

```
UPDATE h
SET IsActivated = 1
FROM [dbo].HRUser h
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM 
    FROM dbo.[UserAudit] a
    WHERE a.UserId = h.UserId AND a.AuditTypeId = 14
)
```

Note that there is no point reopening the target table in the subquery; you just need to correlate it with the outer query.

Comment: I thought of using In or Exists but I was skeptical about the performance as there is large data in the Audit table and that’s the reason i was trying to use a join, Thank you I will try using exists

Comment: When you say Select 1 inside the query it will give 1 , how can that work ? And also any specific reason in using alias name instead of table name after UPDATE ?

Comment: @snadell: for performance, consider an index on `UserAudit(UserId, AuditTypeId)`. As for  `SELECT 1`: `EXISTS` just checks if the subquery returns anything (no matter what), so `SELECT 1` is just fine (as would `SELECT *`, or `SELECT NULL`, etc). Finally: the syntax for `UPDATE` in SQL Server is as shown here: the alias in `UPDATE` refers to the alias defined in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: thank you for the explanation nkw it makes more sense to me, if I make update dbo.[HRUser] h set h.IsActivated = 1 where exists(Here goes the sub query you provided) will this make any difference than the 1 above or both the same ? Coming to Index as this is a 1 time script I don’t think it’s required

Answer (score 0):

Two methods below.  Method 1 is NOT recommended for tables "in production with large number of rows".  But it is much easier to code.  Method 2 works in production with no downtime.

Whichever method you choose:  TEST it outside production.  Copy the data from production.  If you cannot do that, then build your own.  Build a toy system.  Highly recommended that you test at some level before running either method in production.

**METHOD 1**:
Updating on a join is straight forward.  Use an alias.  Reminder, this is NOT RECOMMENDED "with large number of rows" AND production running. The SQL Server optimizer most likely will escalate locks on both tables and block the tables until the update completes.  IF you are taking an outage and are not concerned with how long the update takes, this method works.

```
UPDATE U 
SET IsActivated = 1
FROM dbo.[UserAudit] A
JOIN dbo.[HRUser] U ON A.UserId = U.UserId
WHERE A.AuditTypeId = 14
```

**METHOD 2**:
IF you cannot afford to stop your production systems for this update (and most of us cannot), then I recommend that you do 2 things:

1. Set up a loop with the transaction inside the loop. This means that the optimizer will use row locks and not block the entire table. This method may take longer, but it will not block production.  If the update takes longer, not a concern as long as the devops team never calls because production is blocked.
2. Capture rows to be updated outside the transaction.  THEN, update based on a primary key (fastest).  The total transaction time is how long the rows updated will be blocked.

Here is a toy example for looping.

```
-- STEP 1:  get data to be updated
CREATE TABLE #selected ( ndx INT IDENTITY(1,1), UserId INT )
INSERT INTO #selected (UserId)
SELECT UserId 
FROM dbo.[UserAudit] A
JOIN dbo.[HRUser] U ON A.UserId = U.UserId
WHERE A.AuditTypeId = 14

-- STEP 2:  update on primary key in steps of 1000
DECLARE @RowsToUpdate INT = 1000
    , @LastId INT = 0
    , @RowCnt INT = 0


DECLARE @v TABLE(ndx INT, UserId INT)

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN 

    DELETE @v 
    
    INSERT INTO @v 
    SELECT TOP(@RowsToUpdate) * 
    FROM #selected WHERE ndx > @LastId
    ORDER BY ndx

    SET @RowCnt = @@ROWCOUNT 
    IF @RowCnt = 0 
    BREAK;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        UPDATE a
        SET IsActivated = 1
        FROM @v v
        JOIN dbo.HRUser a ON a.Id = v.UserId 
    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    SELECT @LastId = MAX(ndx) FROM @v 

END
```